# Website Page structure Issue

Tags: html, directory, web, structure

I had some guy make an html website for me and I am trying to setup the page structures correctly. Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

example.com/

example.com/manufacturers/

example.com/manufacturers/x

example.com/manufacturers/x/modems

example.com/manufacturers/x/modems/type1

Can anyone help me out here on how to achieve this kind of structure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using static files, all you will need to do is put directories with those names in a tree and include an index.html file in each directory.

At your root directory you would have an index.html file for example.com/

Also in your root directory you would have a "manufacturers" directory. Inside the "manufacturers" directory you would also have an index.html file for: example.com/manufacturers/

Repeat this structure for every level.

If you are looking to set up something more automated you are going to have to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will have to know which kind of website you are programming...If its a simple site, you just need to create directories like:

```
index.html
about/about.html
company/abc/index.html
company/def/index.html
...
```

And thats it. 
But if you want to have a dynamic webpage (nowadays used much more) .. You first have to know which backend you are using or want to use.

For example if you want Python-Flask as your backend programming language, 
you can simply something like this would do the job

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('home/blabla')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Whereas @app.route('/') would define the path to the webpage...

Sorry, but I tried to sum up as much as I could in my bad language :)